# C# - Missing TreeView "Sorted" property

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, treeview

**Context:**

*OS:*

Édition Windows 10 Professionnel
Version 21H2
Installé le ‎2021-‎01-‎26
Build du système d’exploitation 19044.1526
Expérience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0

*Dev Tool:*

Updated today !

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (3) (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.1.0

*Project:*

Target framework = .NET 6.0 (migrated from original .NET 5.0 target)

*Issue:*

I'm developing a Winform application containing a TreeView I want to be sorted alphabetically.
MSDN [MSDN Sorted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.sorted?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#applies-to) indicates a "Sorted" TreeView's property to be set to true but I don't see any in the properties of my object (see image).

Where should I find it ? What am I missing ?

[image: TreeView's properties]

[image: While Coding]

Comment: It's set to browseable false, so you have to set the value of the property in The Code behind

Comment: @Leppin Unfortunately, this property doesn't appear either while coding (cf. new image)

Comment: Otherwise, thanks for the information Browsable false :-)

Comment: Ok ! Never mind... this property seems to be hidden ! Didn't know it was possible. Thanks @Leppin

Comment: `Sorted = true` is set internally when you call the `Sort()` method or you set the `TreeViewNodeSorter` property to a non-null value, which in turn calls the `Sort()` method.